# facebook login with unity jumping to first scene in editor

Tags: facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, scene

I am having a strange issue when trying to test the Facebook sdk(login) in Unity Editor. The login procedure works fine, but after successfully logging in (pasting the token generator) , Facebook throws me back in to my first scene instead of staying in the same scene, where the login procedure was started.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Update: Strangly enough, this only happens when "maximize on play" is enabled.

Update: Code snipet:

```
public class UserManager : MonoBehaviour {

      public Button fbLoginButton;
      public Text errorSuccessText;

      public void Start() {

          fbLoginButton.interactable = false;

          FB.Init (OnFBInitComplete);

          fbLoginButton.onClick.AddListener (() => SubmitFBInfo ());

      }

      private void OnFBInitComplete() {
          fbLoginButton.interactable = true;
      }

      private void SubmitFBInfo() {
          FB.Login("email,publish_actions", FBLoginCallback);  
      }

      private void FBLoginCallback(FBResult result) {
          if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
               errorSuccessText.text = "Logged In with Facebook";
      }
}
```

Comment: Add code which you have written for this.

Comment: @rushankshah the code is simple really just the boiler plate code from Facebook, you just have to have a button and a text field and attach them to the script. This is all in my second scene, my first scene is a scene-selection menu

Comment: Is this only happening on the Editor? please note that with the new releases the editor support is being dropped. So I would highly recommend you try this on your actual platform/client and see if it's working as expected.

Comment: @ifaour yeah this was happening only in editor, but now I solved it by reimporting the assets. Why is the editor support being dropped?!

Comment: Glad that it's working for you now. There are many factors involved in making support decisions, we cannot comment on the reason. As I said, some features may not be available in the Editor moving forward.